# contextmenustrip at notify icon that contains 50 items how can i display all the items without scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms

contextmenustrip at notify icon that contains 50 items how can i display all the items without scrollbar.all the items at a time.
For menu I set below properties.

```
menu = new ContextMenuStrip();        
menu.AutoSize = false;         
menu.Height = 600;            
menu.Width = 200;            
menu.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Flow;
FlowLayoutSettings fls = menu.LayoutSettings as FlowLayoutSettings;                    
fls.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;            
menu.CanOverflow = true;
```

For item set below property.

```
item.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.Always;
```

But it is not working for me. It is showing scroll bar only.

Comment: how do you pass in the items?

Comment: I am getting items through config file just loopthrough and adding to menu like this:  menu.items.add(item);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

Add a label and set it's Visibility to false, then, in your for loop, just add the line:

```
for(i)
{
    menu.Items.Add(item);
    menu.DropDownHeight += label.Height;
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: I am tried that but it is showing belo error system.windows.Forms.contextmenustrip does not contain the defination of DropDownHeight. In foreach loop am added text and event to item and that item added to menu

Comment: Whoops! Sorry try `menu.Height += label.Height;`

Comment: Still it is showing scrollbar only.i want to see all the items at a time without scrollbar.here i set below thing for menu item autosize=false and set height and widht item.Text = hostApplication.Name; item.Click += new EventHandler(Left_Click); menu.Height += item.Height; menu.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator()); and image,item.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.Always;

Comment: Still it is showing scrollbar only.i want to see all the items at a time without scrollbar.here i set below thing for menu item autosize=false and set height and widht in foreach loop                item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                    item.Text = hostApplication.Name;
                    item.Click += new EventHandler(Left_Click);
                    menu.Items.Add(item);
                    sep = new ToolStripSeparator();
                    menu.Items.Add(sep);
                    item.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.Always;

Comment: try `item.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.AsNeeded;`

Comment: I tried that option too. AsNeeded and Always are not working. It is display scrollbar only